# DateTime.ParseExact not working in C#, Date format Conversion not working

Tags: c#, datetime, date-conversion

Parse Time not working as I want to convert "13-06-2019 00:00:00"(dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss)  to "06-13-2019 00:00:00"(MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss)

tried with `Convert.toDateTime()` and `DateTime.ParseExact()`

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var a = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var b = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
var c = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", culture);
```

Nothing working in it

Comment: Do you got it as a string or is it already a DateTime?

Comment: So you're saying you have a value `13-06-2019` (dd-MM-yyyy) and then you ask DateTime.Parse**Exact** to parse it using `MM-dd-yyyy` and you're asking why it doesn't work? How about you match the format to the value?

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) structure uses [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) under the hood and there is no 13th month in that calendar.

So, parsing `13` with [`MM` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MM_Specifier) is wrong. I strongly suspect that you try to use  `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` format instead.

```
string a = "13-06-2019 00:00:00";
DateTime  b = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

<kbd>[Here a demonstration](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6dPbUL)</kbd>

Your second and third examples also don't work since their formats are *completely* different than your string. When you parse your string with [`ParseExact` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8), **your strings and your format should match exactly**.

Also I want to mention that, both `hh` and `HH` specifiers would work in my code example. But as a general format consideration, using `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` format is much more common and reliable than the other option.

Answer (score 2):

The format parameter of DateTime.ParseExact(date,format,culture) is the source format of the date string to be converted and the return value is type date which you can convert back to string as per the desired format.

```
var a = "13-06-2019 00:00:00";

IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime b = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine($"{b:MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
```